# why do pycaret use ordinal feature when i have used the option as none in setup

Tags: regression, ordinal, pycaret

in my example of pycaret setup i have used the ordinal_features=None option, but when i print the features, i see pycaret has used some features as ordinal. I dont want it to be ordinal but just consider catogerical.
[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Z1W.png)

[features print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGN8s.png)

i tried the ordinal_feature as null option and also tried giving this as all categorical fatures, but still i see pycaret treats it as ordinal